# Query returns 0 results in php, but in oracle SQL developer it returns 52 results

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a problem with with my oracle query. When I run it in PHP, it returns 0 results. If I run the same Query in Oracle SQLDeveloper, it returns 52 results.

This is the query in PHP:

```
SELECT name , zipcity FROM  import_persons WHERE upper(:zoekop) LIKE '%:zoekwaarde%' AND status < 3 ORDER BY name
$parameters = array(':zoekop' => $zoekop, ':zoekwaarde' => $zoekwaarde);
```

The query I run in SQLDeveloper, with the variables filled in manually.(Copied them from an echo in the PHP).

```
SELECT  name , zipcity FROM import_persons WHERE upper(name) LIKE '%Q%' AND status < 3 ORDER BY name
```

I can't seem to find the error, before asking, I tried to bind the params but that didn't work.

Comment: I've moved the addendum answer to its own answer post, so questions and answers are kept nicely separated (helpful mainly for data extract and API users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

```
SELECT name , zipcity FROM  import_persons
    WHERE UPPER(:zoekop) LIKE '%:zoekwaarde%' AND status < 3
    ORDER BY name
```

It is good you're using bound parameters, but unfortunately only values can be bound; since `:zoekop` is a placeholder for a column, you'll have to use traditional string concatenation (and if the column name comes from user input, use a whitelist for security).

You can bind for  `:zoekwaarde`, but the wildcards need to be part of the string you bind, not in the query. Your SQL will therefore look a bit like this:

```
SELECT name , zipcity FROM  import_persons
    WHERE UPPER(zoekop_col) LIKE :zoekwaarde AND status < 3
    ORDER BY name
```

Notice that the query does not include quotes - they are not required, since the binding system knows the type of the parameter you are binding in this position. Wrapping it all up, you now only have one parameter to bind:

```
$parameters = array(':zoekwaarde' => "%{$zoekwaarde}%", );
```

Comment: No probs @McBurgerKong, pleased that's got it working!

Comment: @McBurgerKong: it may be worth adding some error checking to your query call - I think the original code should have resulted in an error, but I wonder if you did not see that. With databases it is always good to check for errors at runtime, as much as possible.

Comment: Now you say that I should've indeed. I did not see any error when I executed, but maybe if I checked using the PDO functions errorCode and errorInfo I would've seen earlier. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: Yes @McBurgerKong, you would need to test for errors explicitly, and it's still worth doing now. Of course, don't show technical errors to users in production - just in dev/staging.

Comment: Yes it truly worth your while. @halfer I would never do that indeed, I only show things on my test server, and when I deploy I make sure every debug info is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know PHP so this is a bit of a guess, but i wonder if the

```
LIKE '%:zoekwaarde%'
```

is taking the variable name as a literal string and you many be better off with something like

```
LIKE '%' || :zoekwaarde || '%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I've tried this and still get no results in PHP. SQLDeveloper still gives results, even with the edit you suggested

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to hard code in the values in your PHP code just to prove that it's a problem with the variables. But as i don't know PHP I will have to bow out on this, good luck with finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

Thanks to halfer's answer, I was able to fix the problem. The fix:

```
$query_01 = "SELECT name , zipcity FROM  import_persons WHERE upper(name) LIKE :zoekwaarde AND status < 3 ORDER BY name";
$parameters = array(':zoekwaarde' => "%{$zoekwaarde}%", );
```

Comment: OP, if you wish to add your own answer (so that you can possibly get upvotes for doing so) then let me know, so I can delete this one. Thanks!